# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CartList> above this Consumer<CartList> Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

This is a part of code for run app:

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => _number != null?ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (context)=>CartList(),
                    child: HomeScreenDemo(),
                  ):Login())));
```

**I've also tried using MultiProvider instead of ChangeNotifierProvider but it didn't work.**

This is the part of Code for home Screen:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Consumer<CartList>(
      builder: (context,CART,child){
        return  Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
)
```

This is how I'm Navigating to checkOut Screen:

```
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => CartScreen(userPin: _userPin,)
                                  ));
```

This is the code of checkOut Screen:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context)=>Consumer<CartList>(
        builder: (context,cart,child){
          return  Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
```

**I've tried removing builder before Consumer But it didn't work.**

This Is the ScreenShot of error:

[image]

Here I'm pushing the route:

```
   showCart? Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Container(

                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),color: Colors.cyan,

                            ),
                            child: Material(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: InkWell(
                                splashColor: Colors.black12,
                                onTap: () {
                                  //  Cart OnClick
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                                          value: Provider.of<CartList>(context, listen: false),
                                          child: CartScreen(userPin: _userPin,)
                                      )
                                  ));
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),

                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(CART.count<=1?CART.count.toString()+"  ITEM":CART.count.toString()+"  ITEMS",style: TextStyle(
                                              letterSpacing: 1.5,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                          ),),
                                          SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                          Text(" ₹"+CART.totalPrice.toString().replaceAll(regex, "")),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 160,),
                                      Text('Cart ',style: TextStyle( fontSize: 18,letterSpacing: .5,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),textAlign: TextAlign.end,),
                                      Icon(Icons.arrow_right,size: 30,),

                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  height: 60,


                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ):Container()
```

Comment: use provider one level above

Comment: You fell for the first case described in the error message. The provider you are trying to read is likely in a different route.

Comment: @SachinBhankhar, how should I do that and where, can you please share a snippet of code for that. It will be really grateful.

Comment: @RémiRousselet, Where I did the wrong, I shared my whole code where I use Provider.

Comment: can you provide the complete widget where you are pushing route

Comment: @SachinBhankhar, I've added the complete widget where I'm pushing the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the widget tree in Android Studio or VS and you will see that when pushing a route it starts fresh with only MaterialApp (Unless you create the Provider before the MaterialApp) above so there is no CartList to consume, wrap it in a ChangeNotifierProvider.value to expose a previous created provider

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value( //this context change its name to something else to avoid confusion
       value: Provider.of<CartList>(context, listen: false),
       child: CartScreen(userPin: _userPin,)
     )
));
```

Comment: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CartList> above this Builder Widget .Getting this  error.

Comment: it will not work as official docs says don't use ChangeNotifierProvider.value to create objects

Comment: I'm not creating, I'm exposing it's value to the next route

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-readme-tab- check out the section exposing the vaule you should use Provider not Provider.value

Comment: If you already have an object instance and want to expose it, you should use the .value constructor of a provider.

Comment: @EdwynZN, What should I do now for the above error?

Comment: I updated the code, try changing the name of the context in the builder of MaterialPageRoute, maybe when exposing the provider is using that name instead of the context of the HomeScreen

Comment: what i do i wrap the MaterialApp with MutliProvider and provide all the providers right there.

Comment: @EdwynZN, Thanks you so much. This Worked.

Comment: @EdwynZN https://pub.dev/packages/provider#exposing-a-value  this says if your .value also recreate the object use Provider to expose value. Can you explain if I'm thing something wrong.

Comment: sorry I didn't find where it says that, only the first part where it says To expose a newly created object, use the default constructor of a provider. Do not use the .value constructor if you want to create an object, if a provider its already created, and you want to expose it to a place where it cannot be exposed directly the best choice its to use .value instead of recreating it, to avoid undesirable effects